# Recognizing rtf formats

Tags: rtf

I am writing code that will do conversion from `rtf` to `txt`.

When giving a rtf formatted text to my method, firstly it has to check if it is has rtf format. If it's not then just do nothing.

My question:

Do rtf files **always** (remark on always) begin with `{\rtf1`? If it does, then I can do my check on that.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, Yes

This is from the 1.9.1 RTF specification

"The *\rtfN* control word must follow the opening brace. The numeric parameter *N* identifies the major version of the RTF Specification used."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temp RichTextBox.

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
try
{
    rtb.RTF=rtf; // rtf is the rtf data you want to convert
    text = rtb.Text;
}
catch
{
    // invalid RTF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid rtf file always starts with the `{\rtf` sequence and ends with a closing `}`. Although, the number followed by the `{\rtf` tag is supposed to be the version number, it is generally ignored.  Word still uses `{\rtf1` for the opening sequence.